# Add index signature to a function in .d.ts

Tags: typescript, function-object, .d.ts, index-signature

I want to overwrite npm library typing to add index signature to a function. Let's say the function does nothing spectacular:

```js
export function foo(input) {
  return Number(input);
}
```

It has a typing in `.d.ts` file:

```js
export default function foo(input: string): number | null;
```

I want to add properties to this function, like:

```js
foo['something'] = 2;
```

How to change `.d.ts` file so it will allow me to do this with **any** property not only `something`?
It should have index signature of `[index: string]: number;`. I have found answers how to do it, but only for a single or few known properties, but I need to put any string as a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself by merging function with object (typed with index signature) using `Object.assign` on TSPlayground and it can generate `.d.ts` for me:

```js
declare const foo: ((input: string) => number | null) & {
  [key: string]: number;
};

export default parse;
```